# ios audio input and output via rtp stream

Tags: ios, audio, voip, rtp

I want to create an App, which can play sound received by rtp-stream and capture sound from the microphone and send it via rtp-stream. The problem is, that I have no idea how to start. Can someone tell me a library for rtp-streaming on ios devices? I took a look at Live555, but I didn't understand how it works.

Thanks